# PHP: Find the missing digit x from the given expression

Tags: php

Have the function **MissingDigit (str)** take the **str** parameter, which will be a simple mathematical formula with three numbers, a single operator (+, -, *, or /) and an equal sign (=) and return the digit that completes the equation. In one of the numbers in the equation, there will be an x character, and your program should determine what digit is missing. For example, if **str** is **"3x + 12 = 46"** then your program should output 4. The **x** character can appear in any of the three numbers and all three numbers will be greater than or equal to 0 and less than or equal to 1000000.

````
function MissingDigit($str) {

   // code goes here
   return $str;
}
// keep this function call here
echo MissingDigit ("3x + 12 = 46");

?>```
````

Comment: Hello. Interesting. But what have you already tried?

Comment: " 0x + 12 = 46 " ?

Comment: i want to find x value from give expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting proper solution from [here](https://thephpguru.com/php/php-find-the-missing-digit-from-given-expression/).

There is solution for getting **x** value from first operand, second operand or even in result,

example:

```
Input: S = “4x + 16 = 60”
Output: 4

Input: S = “8 - 5 = x”
Output: 3

Input: S = “40 - 2x = 19”
Output: 1
```

I was searches many time on google and i see many codes but i found best solution in [The PHP Guru](https://thephpguru.com/php/php-find-the-missing-digit-from-given-expression/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function MissingDigit($str) {

$parts = explode('=',$str);
if (strpos($parts[1],'x') !== false) {
    $aux  = $parts[1];
    $parts[1] = $parts[0];
    $parts[0] = $aux;
}
$operands = preg_split('/(\+|\-|\*|\/)/', $parts[0]);

$detectSign = function($a) {
    $signs = ['+','-','/','*'];
    foreach ($signs as $s) {
        if (strpos($a,$s)){
            return $s;
        }
    }
    return;
};
$op = $operands[0];
$xoperand = $operands[1];
if (strpos($operands[0],'x') !== null ) {
    $op = $operands[1];
    $xoperand = $operands[0];
}
$sign = $detectSign($parts[0]);

$opozite = ['+'=>'-','-'=>'+','/'=>'*','*'=>'/'];

$result = eval('return '.$parts[1].(string)$opozite[$sign].(string)$op.';');
return str_replace(str_split(strtolower($xoperand)), '', strtolower($result));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I  am sharing the universal solution which can pass all test cases
Please convert this logic according to php
Javascript code:

```
function operationForResultant(operator, operand1, operand2) {
    let res = 0;
    if (operator == "+") res = operand1 + operand2;
    else if (operator == "-") res = operand1 - operand2;
    else if (operator == "*") res = operand1 * operand2;
    else res = Math.floor(operand1 / operand2);
    return res;
}

function opposite(operator, operand1, operand2) {
    if (operator == "+") return "-";
    else if (operator == "-") return "+";
    else if (operator == "*") return "/";
    else return "*";
}

function MissingDigit(exp) {
    let res = 0,
        expressionWithX;

    exp = exp.split(" ");

    let operand1 = exp[0];
    let operator = exp[1];
    let operand2 = exp[2];
    let resultant = exp[exp.length - 1];

    // If x is present in resultant
    if (resultant.indexOf("x") != -1) {
        expressionWithX = resultant;
        operand1 = Number(operand1);
        operand2 = Number(operand2);
        res = operationForResultant(operator, operand1, operand2);
    }

    // If x in present in operands
    else {
        resultant = Number(resultant);
        if (operand1.indexOf("x") != -1) {
            expressionWithX = operand1;
            operand2 = Number(operand2);
            res = operationForResultant(opposite(operator), resultant, operand2);
        }

        // If x is in the second operand
        else {
            expressionWithX = operand2;
            operand1 = Number(operand1);
            if (operator == "+" || operator == "*") {
                res = operationForResultant(opposite(operator), resultant, operand1);
            } else {
                res = operationForResultant(operator, operand1, resultant);
            }
        }
    }
    res = res.toString();
    return res[expressionWithX.indexOf("x")].toString();
}

let exp = "3x + 12 = 46";
// let exp =  "4 - 2 = x"

console.log(MissingDigit(exp));
```

Output:
4